# Authorize attribute always denied even if in correct group

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, ef-core-3.1

I am having issues with the authorise attribute in that its always denied even though I have roles setup for admin and manager. This is the code to the stadnard login identiy page I have a feeling I am missing something that when the users login in they should be added to the role?. I am using .net core 3.1 and ef core

I feel that I need to be using or something that finds which role the user belongs to and assigns them to it?

```
 await userStore.AddToRoleAsync(user, "admin");
```

Somewhere in the below

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
           
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
            string Intitals = user.FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + user.LastName.Substring(0, 1);
            _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("Intitals", Intitals);

            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Edit 2

I tried even adding this into startup but I am still getting access is denied when I have the user in the correct group.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 options.AddPolicy("MISSystem",
 policy => policy.RequireClaim("manager", "admin", "agent")));
```

**Edit 3**
Folks the below did not solve it for me so I created a reproducable version here.

https://github.com/davidbuckleyni/AuthorisationRepoMS

Also before I fogot to include my claim factory code I am including here below.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MISSystem.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MISSystem.Web.Helpers {
    public class MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> {
        public MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
                : base(userManager, optionsAccessor) {
        }

        protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user) {
            var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName ?? "[Click to edit profile]"));
            return identity;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Finally found the reason for some reason in another example they where using a custom claim factory my code does not actually require that so once I removed this line.

.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory();

It worked as expected for the manager attribute

Answer (score -1):

> This is the code to the stadnard login identiy page I have a feeling I am missing something that when the users login in they should be added to the role?

You can use [UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(TUser, String) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.addtoroleasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to add specific user to role, like below.

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("test@example.com");

await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "admin");
```

And you can check if expected record (UserId-RoleId) is indeed added in database `AspNetUserRoles` table

[image]

Besides, please make sure you have create `admin` role using [RoleManager.CreateAsync(TRole) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.rolemanager-1.createasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Hi Feri I understand that but how does one find out what role the user belongs to. I already have them in the role table from my managment screen

Comment: `how does one find out what role the user belongs to` You can use [`UserManager<TUser>.GetRolesAsync(TUser)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getrolesasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to get role names the specified user belongs to.

Comment: The user is already on the role what I mean is is there not a cookie you need to set so that the authorise anotations work correct with the the users role in it.

Comment: Please see my edits above the user is in the correct role